# Cannot http file upload with libcurl.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, libcurl

I am using libcurnet for posting some fields and html or pdf file to server. I post fields but can not upload file to server. Here is my code :

> public static void Main(String[] args)
>   {     try    {
>       Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
>
> ```
> FileStream fs = new
> FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
>
> Easy easy = new Easy();
>
> Easy.ReadFunction rf = new Easy.ReadFunction(OnReadData);
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_READFUNCTION,rf);
>
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_PUT, true);
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, args[1]);
>
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_READDATA, fs);
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, fs.Length);
>
> Easy.DebugFunction df = new Easy.DebugFunction(OnDebug);
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, df);
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
>
> Easy.ProgressFunction pf = new Easy.ProgressFunction(OnProgress);
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, pf);
>
> Easy.WriteFunction wf = new Easy.WriteFunction(OnWriteData);
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wf);
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, args[2]);
>
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla 4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Win32");
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
>
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POST, true);
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
> easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_STDERR, 0);
>
> easy.Perform();
> easy.Cleanup();
>
> fs.Close();
> Curl.GlobalCleanup();    }    catch (Exception ex)    {
>   Console.WriteLine(ex);    }  }
> ```

I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fiddler2 to spy on the TCP stream, particularly the header part, and compare it to performing a manual upload from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the library itself you have downloaded from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/dotnet/). If so, try to use upload sample from  **/samples/FileUpload.cs**

Something like this.

```
        MultiPartForm mf = new MultiPartForm();        

        // <input type="File" name="f1">
        mf.AddSection(CURLformoption.CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "uploadedfile",
            CURLformoption.CURLFORM_FILE, "C:\\My Files\myUploadFile.exe",
            CURLformoption.CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "application/binary",
            CURLformoption.CURLFORM_END);

        Easy easy = new Easy();
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, mf);
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, "localhost/uploader.php");
```

Don't forget to change "upload_max_filesize" in php.ini on server for files more then 2Mb.

In file "uploader.php" you need writing something like this.

```
<?php
  $target_path = "/uploaded/". basename( $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)) 
  {     
    echo "[File Upload Successful]";
  } 
  else
  {
    echo "[File Upload Error]";
  }
?>
```